# chrome extension bottom window similar to firebug

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a bottom window similar to what firebug has...

I know I need to use content script, but how and where do I insert this window/bar?...

any help or ideas would be really appreciated.

thanks

Comment: There's the sidebar proposal ( http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/sidebar-extension-api ), but I haven't seen anything that would allow vertical bars. Maybe post a message to https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you wanted right now is using Content Scripts and inject DOM (div, or iframe) at the bottom of each page. (Ugly solution, might not always work, but only way to do this until the sidebar proposal gets finalized)